# Cannot select the results that come out from place autocomplete Google Maps API

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to us a google maps API in my code. I succeeded in putting a map inside my app and also made a textfield where I can put a location and five different predictions would come up due to the place autocomplete API. However, I get a exception error of no candidates found whenever I try to press on the prediction. I want to change to code to make that map go to the certain location that I select on the prediction. For example, if I click on USA which will be on the first prediction list when I type in USA in my textfield, I want that camera of the map to go to USA. I have no idea how I can fix this please help me.

Here are the codes that I am using:

The main mapscreen code:

```
class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapSample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => _MapSampleState();
}

class _MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  late CameraPosition _cameraPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cameraPosition =
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(35.6895, 139.6917), zoom: 17);
  }

  late GoogleMapController _mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<LocationController>(
      builder: (locationController) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Maps Sample App'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController mapController) {
                      _mapController = mapController;
                    },
                    initialCameraPosition: _cameraPosition),
                Positioned(
                  top: 100,
                  left: 10,
                  right: 20,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => LocationSearchDialog(
                          mapController: _mapController,
                        ),
                      );
                    },                    child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      child: Row(children: [
                        Icon(Icons.location_on,
                            size: 25, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        //here we show the address on the top
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            '${locationController.pickPlaceMark.name ?? ''} ${locationController.pickPlaceMark.locality ?? ''} '
                            '${locationController.pickPlaceMark.postalCode ?? ''} ${locationController.pickPlaceMark.country ?? ''}',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Icon(Icons.search,
                            size: 25,
                            color:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!.color),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The prediction function widget:

```
   class LocationService {
      final String key = 'ApiCode';
    
      Future<String> getPlaceId(String input) async {
        final String url =
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$key';
    
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
        var status = json['status'] as String;
    
        if (status == 'OK') {
          var candidates = json['candidates'] as List<dynamic>;
          if (candidates.isNotEmpty) {
            var placeId = candidates[0]['place_id'] as String;
            return placeId;
          }
        }
    
        throw Exception('No candidates found');
      }
    
    
    
      Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPlace(String input) async {
        final placeId = await getPlaceId(input);
        final String url =
            'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$placeId&key=$key';
    
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
        var results = json['result'] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
        print(results); // Debugging print statement
    
        return results;
      }
    }
    
    
    class LocationController extends GetxController {
      Placemark _pickPlaceMark = Placemark();
      Placemark get pickPlaceMark => _pickPlaceMark;
    
      List<Prediction> _predictionList = [];
    
      Future<List<Prediction>> searchLocation(BuildContext context, String text) async {
        if (text != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
          http.Response response = await getLocationData(text);
          var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
          print("my status is " + data["status"]);
          if (data['status'] == 'OK') {
            _predictionList = [];
            data['predictions'].forEach((prediction) =>
                _predictionList.add(Prediction.fromJson(prediction)));
          } else {
            // ApiChecker.checkApi(response);
          }
        }
        return _predictionList;
      }
    
      Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPlace(String placeId) async {
        final locationService = LocationService();
        return await locationService.getPlace(placeId);
      }
    }
    
    Future<http.Response> getLocationData(String text) async {
      http.Response response;
    
      response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("http://mvs.bslmeiyu.com/api/v1/config/place-api-autocomplete?search_text=$text"),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      );
    
      print(jsonDecode(response.body));
      return response;
    }
```

and my search dialogue code:

```
class LocationSearchDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final GoogleMapController? mapController;
  const LocationSearchDialog({required this.mapController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Material(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 350,
          child: TypeAheadField(
            textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller: _controller,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
              autofocus: true,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'search_location',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(style: BorderStyle.none, width: 0),
                ),
                hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2?.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
                ),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              ),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2?.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.color,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
            suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
              return await Get.find<LocationController>()
                  .searchLocation(context, pattern);
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, Prediction suggestion) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        suggestion.description!,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2?.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.color,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            onSuggestionSelected: (Prediction suggestion) {
              _onSuggestionSelected(context, suggestion);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onSuggestionSelected(BuildContext context, Prediction suggestion) async {
    final locationController = Get.find<LocationController>();
    final locationDetails =
    await locationController.getPlace(suggestion.placeId!);
    final lat = locationDetails['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    final lng = locationDetails['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    final newCameraPosition =
    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 17);

    mapController?.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(newCameraPosition),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

I know these are a lot of code but please help me if you know what the problem is.